# Display profile data from database when login

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm pretty much a beginner to php since I've shift. My registration is working fine and log in(checking if its in the database). I'm getting confused on using the session(display user who's logged in).

This is my `login.php`: (working fine)

```
<?php
$Regusername = $_POST['username'];
$Regpassword = $_POST['password'];

$dbc = @mysql_connect('localhost' , 'root','');
@mysql_select_db('market', $dbc);

$query1 = "SELECT username FROM customer WHERE password='$Regpassword' and username='$Regusername'";

$r1 = @mysql_query($query1, $dbc); // user
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($r1); // 

if ($row1['username'] == $Regusername && $Regpassword) { 
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username']==$row1['username'];
    Header("Location: home.php");
  }
else
  { print '<p> <h1> Ooops, error login, please try again. </h1></p>'; }
?>
```

then in my profile.php. At the top I've already added  "*$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');*"

```
<?php
  session_start(); // Start Session Data
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
?>


<?php  
  echo "Name: ".$_SESSION['username']."" ; //Undefined index: username in this line, the error shows up. 
?>
```

t only displays *Name:*
Hope somebody helps me of what am I missing or should change here.
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the session is set? `if ($row1['username'] == $Regusername && $Regpassword) { ` looks off to me.

Comment: Did you check the database to make sure the username is being saved in it?

Comment: @Daniel  - I used it to check in database .. Should i remove somewhere here or change?

Comment: @wuno yes i really do have it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you never set the session:

```
$_SESSION['username']==$row1['username']; // is the same as 1=1 = true
```

that is a logical "query" meaning that session is row = true. however, it is supposed to be a statement where you set session to equal row. remove one of the equal signs.

also, this line looks rather confusing

```
if ($row1['username'] == $Regusername && $Regpassword)
```

Comment: ohmygad it worked. i just removed one = . thank you so much..
that line works fine here ..